# Web API - Client Certification Authentication

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a web api, which developers in my organization call through AJAX.
The way I am authenticating users is through client certs. however, because you can't attach certs with AJAX, it is done by the browser. the problem is whenever a call is made to the api, the browser pops up a window saying select a certificate.

is there any way of getting around this pop up window?

if not, what other authentication can I use to identify the calling clients and if they have the right to call the api. The clients are web applications, which are authenticated by AD groups themselves, so I can't implement basic authentication for the api.